# Sending Email in Android using JavaMail API

Tags: android, android-intent, jakarta-mail

I am following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a) tutorial for sending Emails from My App.

When i try to run this in my device its getting error as authentication failed because of Google New Policy

here is screenshot of google mail[image]

so is there any updated solution for send email in background ?

Comment: Have you tried turning [this](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) off?

Comment: I think your question was already answered here:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Comment: You also might want to try this [development version of JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android), especially if you want to use [OAuth2 authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) instead of enabling support for less secure apps.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to properly setup your Gmail account.**

If you have **2-step verification** enabled:

- Please follow [this tutorial](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en) to create an app password for your app.

If you don't have 2-step verification enabled:

- Simply enable less secure apps login [here](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps).

I don't recommend it, though. I believe your password is stored *in plain text* as a String value, right?
A little bit of reverse engineering and it's out in the public.

Comment: yes I have enable now , but still got authentication failed exception

Comment: Great! If my answer helped you on that, please mark it as correct. Otherwise, I recommend you answer this question yourself with details on how you fixed it. :)